# elastic search object association querying through params

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I'm having some difficulty with Elastic Search and Tire not returning any results. I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.11.

In my controller I'm calling:

```
@location_id = 1
@listings = Listing.search(params.merge!(location_id: @location_id))
```

In my listing model I have

```
mapping do
    indexes :id, type: 'integer'
    ...
    indexes :author do
      indexes :location_id,     :type => 'integer', :index => :not_analyzed
      ...
end

def self.search(params={})
      tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 20) do |search|

      search.query  { string params[:query], :default_operator => "AND" } if params[:query].present?
      search.filter :range, posted_at: {lte: DateTime.now}

      search.filter :term, "author.location_id"       => params[:location_id]
end
```

I have 300 results which all have the location_id of 1 in the database so I can't seem to figure out why it's returning a nil set? If I comment out the author.location_id search filter line it returns all other results as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things which needs to be adressed in a situation like yours. Let's start with a fully working code:

```
require 'active_record'
require 'tire'
require 'logger'

# Tire.configure { logger STDERR }
# ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDERR)

Tire.index('articles').delete

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection( adapter: 'sqlite3', database: ":memory:" )
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 1) do
  create_table :articles do |t|
    t.string :title
    t.integer :author_id
    t.date    :posted_at
    t.timestamps
  end
  create_table :authors do |t|
    t.string  :name
    t.integer :number, :location_id
    t.timestamps
  end
  add_index(:articles, :author_id)
  add_index(:authors, :location_id)
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, touch: true
  self.include_root_in_json = false

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  mapping do
    indexes :title

    indexes :author do
      indexes :location_id, type: 'integer'
    end
  end

  def self.search(params={})
    tire.search load: {include: 'author'} do |search|
      search.query do |query|
        query.filtered do |f|
          f.query { params[:query].present? ? match([:title], params[:query], operator: 'and') : match_all }
          f.filter :range, 'posted_at' => { lte: DateTime.now }
          f.filter :term,  'author.location_id' => params[:location_id]
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def to_indexed_json
    to_json( only: ['title', 'posted_at'], include: { author: { only: [:location_id] } } )
  end
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles

  after_touch do
    articles.each { |a| a.tire.update_index }
  end
end

# -----

Author.create id: 1, name: 'John', location_id: 1
Author.create id: 2, name: 'Mary', location_id: 1
Author.create id: 3, name: 'Abby', location_id: 2

Article.create title: 'Test A', author: Author.find(1), posted_at: 2.days.ago
Article.create title: 'Test B', author: Author.find(2), posted_at: 1.day.ago
Article.create title: 'Test C', author: Author.find(3), posted_at: 1.day.ago
Article.create title: 'Test D', author: Author.find(3), posted_at: 1.day.from_now

Article.index.refresh

# -----

articles = Article.search query: 'test', location_id: 1
puts "", "Documents with location:1", '-'*80
articles.results.each { |a| puts "* TITLE: #{a.title}, LOCATION: #{a.author.location_id}, DATE: #{a.posted_at}" }

articles = Article.search query: 'test', location_id: 2
puts "", "Documents with location:2", '-'*80
articles.results.each { |a| puts "* TITLE: #{a.title}, LOCATION: #{a.author.location_id}, DATE: #{a.posted_at}" }
puts "(NOTE: 'D' is missing, because is not yet posted)"

articles = Article.search query: 'test b', location_id: 1
puts "", "Documents with query:B and location:1", '-'*80
articles.results.each { |a| puts "* TITLE: #{a.title}, LOCATION: #{a.author.location_id}, DATE: #{a.posted_at}" }
```

First, it's usually a good idea to create an isolated, extracted case like this.

In your example code, I assume you have a relationship `Listing belongs_to :author`. You need to properly define the mapping and serialization, which I again assume you did.

As for the query itself:

- Unless you're using faceted navigation, use the `filtered` query, not top level filters, as in my example code.
- Do not use the `string` query, unless you really want to expose all the power (and fragility!) of the Lucene query string query to your users.
- Use the `match` query, as your "generic purpose" query -- *Tire* sprinkles some sugar on top of it, allowing to easily create `multi_match` queries, etc
- The filter syntax in your example is correct. When the `filter` method is called multiple times in *Tire*, it creates and `and` filter.

Uncomment the Tire logging configuration (and possibly also the ActiveRecord logging), to see what the code is doing.